# How to get an DHCP allocated IP address without a reboot?

Tags: ip, dhcp, static-ip

I have a server which currently staticly addressed with an entry in its `/etc/hosts` file, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.1.91 docker docker.local
```

I'd like to introduce this server to DHCP so I can let it have its static IP from the DHCP server.

For that, I plan to change the server's `/etc/hosts` to:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 docker docker.local
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

#192.168.1.91 docker docker.local
```

However, once I did that, **what do I have to do to ask the DHCP server to allocate an address to docker.local - without rebooting docker.local** (it's on CentOS 7)**?**

I suspect I'd have to do `sudo ifdown enp132s0 && sudo ifup eth0`, but am not sure if that'd be all.

Note that `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp132s0` also hardcodes the IP:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="enp132s0"
UUID="4ccacac5-fd8a-46a7-9279-6f9fea7d066e"
DEVICE="enp132s0"
ONBOOT="yes"
DNS1=8.8.8.8
IPADDR=192.168.1.91
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.99
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Comment: The `/etc/hosts` is related to DNS and has nothing to do with static IP vs. DHCP.

Answer (score 2):

The hosts file has nothing to do with IP addressing.

Modify `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp132s0` and change `BOOTPROTO` to `DHCP`. Remove the other IP address info:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=DHCP
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="enp132s0"
UUID="4ccacac5-fd8a-46a7-9279-6f9fea7d066e"
DEVICE="enp132s0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Restart your network interface to apply the changes.